Can the package name of a 2nd generation managed package be changed after it's released?
I have released a 2nd gen managed package with an incorrect name and the package is istalled in the customer`s org so now I want to change the package name in the next version release so is it possible to change the package name now?
Note : I am talking about PackageName not namespace and in 2nd gen packaging the versioning is dependent on packagename.
please check below image where green arrow is pointed


Namespace of manage package can't be changed after it is released.  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/sfdx_dev_reg_namespace.htm
However Package label You can change with every new release.

Appologies for the confusion I have updated my post with more details and I am talking about PackageName not Namespace.
